# 403 - Failed To Load Resource(Forbidden)

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I have just started using XAMMP to develope with php as I dont have an actual web hosted server. When I try to laod images locally I get the 403 - Failed To Load Resource(Forbidden) error. Does anyone know how to fix this or allow it so I can load this image. I have tried running chrome with flags and it still did not work. Thankyou

Comment: Check permissions for XAMMP on the images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this address and use it when uploading
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)